# WPF User Control doesn't show up in grid

Tags: wpf, grid, user-controls

Im trying to add a UserControl in WPF to a grid, but it doesnt show up when im trying to add via MyGrid.Children.Add(UserControl). So i tried to display the number of childs of my grid and it says 1 after adding the usercontrol. (MyGrid.Children.Clear() doesn't work too. After clearing the grid it says that there are 0 childs left but there are still some UiElements when im compiling my program.)

This problem appears only in 1 function. In an other function (the same class) i can easily add childs to the same grid (myGrid).

My code:

```
        private void AddDateOnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
             MyGrid.Children.Clear();           
             UserControlAddDate ucad = new UserControlAddDate();
             MyGrid.Children.Add(ucad);
             MessageBox.Show(MyGrid.Children.Count.ToString());  //Only to test if there are some childs
        }
```

When i try to clear this grid in a other function (same class) it clears the grid. Only clearing in this function is a problem. Im not understanding why???

Comment: Use templates and databinding. Don't waste your time fighting against the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this UserControlAddDate? Maybe it is not initialized. That’s why it’s not getting added to the grid..
In that place try to add a textbox to the grid and check if it’s working. If it’s working then it’s the problem with your code.

As mentioned by Ed Plunkett, please try to use templates and databinding. It's the best way to work with WPF.

Try this anyway.

```
private void AddDateOnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     MyGrid.Children.Clear();           
     TextBox ucad = new TextBox();
     ucad.Text = “TEST”;
     MyGrid.Children.Add(ucad);
     MessageBox.Show(MyGrid.Children.Count.ToString());  //Only to test if there are some childs
}
```